# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: php, android, json

I am creating application where the user enters data to search and then application sends it to server and then server sends search result back to the client.

I am getting error with i am not able to understand what it means. I am getting exact result from the server.

here is my networking code from there application and here is [link to full code](http://pastebin.com/is7R2j38)

```
     public class GetDatafromDB_Searchresult {
            String response1 ;


            public String getDataFromDB() {
 httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.106/test/search.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
                    //add your data
                    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("carat1", strcarat1.toString().trim()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("carat2", strcarat2.toString().trim()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("carat1", strcolor1.toString().trim()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("carat2", strcolor2.toString().trim()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("clarity1", strclarity1.toString().trim()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("clarity2", strclarity2.toString().trim()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cut1", strcut1.toString().trim()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cut2", strcut2.toString().trim()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("shape1", strshape1.toString().trim()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("shape2", strshape2.toString().trim()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stones", strstone.toString().trim()));


                    // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];

                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        //Execute HTTP Post Request


                try {
                        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity= response.getEntity();
                    {
                        if(entity!=null)
                        {
                            entity.consumeContent();
                        }
                    }

                    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                     response1 = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
                    System.out.println("Response : " + response1);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());

                }


                return response1.trim();

            }
        }
```

here is my server side code

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="testdb";
$username_localhost ="root";
$password_localhost ="";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

 mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

$carat1 = $_POST['carat1'];
$carat2 = $_POST['carat2'];
$clarity1 = $_POST['clarity1'];
$clarity2 = $_POST['clarity2'];
$color1 = $_POST['color1'];
$color2 = $_POST['color2'];
$cut1 = $_POST['cut1'];
$cut2 = $_POST['cut2'];
$shape1 = $_POST['shape1'];
$shape2 = $_POST['shape2'];
$stones = $_POST['stones'];

$query_search ="Select * from search1 where carats Between '$carat1' and '$carat2' and 
color = '$color1' or color =  '$color2' and cut = '$cut1' or cut = '$cut2' and shape = '$shape1' or shape =  '$shape2' and stone ='$stones' ";

$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());


    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_exec))
            $json_output[]=$row;
      echo json_encode($json_output);

    mysql_close();

?>
```

Also i did change  echo json_encode($json_output); to  print(json_encode($json_output)); and still there is no chamnge in output

here is my output from logcat.

```
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: color1 in C:\wamp\www\test\search.php on line <i>16</i></th></tr>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>147496</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\test\search.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\search.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ </table></font>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <br />
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: color2 in C:\wamp\www\test\search.php on line <i>17</i></th></tr>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>147496</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\test\search.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\search.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ </table></font>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ [{"id":"4","product_code":"4","shape":"Asscher","pair":"jgj","carats":"1.8","color":"G","clarity":"VS2","service":"iuhi","polish":"hiihi","symetric":"hih","tables":"ihi","measurments":"hi","flourscne":"hi","description":"ih","certificated":"hjgj","ccode":"hjgj","cut":"Signature Ideal","total":"iuhiu","file":"hiuhih","stone":"Single"}]
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <br />
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: color1 in C:\wamp\www\test\search.php on line <i>16</i></th></tr>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>147496</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\test\search.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\search.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ </table></font>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <br />
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: color2 in C:\wamp\www\test\search.php on line <i>17</i></th></tr>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>147496</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\test\search.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\search.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ </table></font>
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1566/com.diamond.traders I/System.out﹕ [{"id":"4","product_code":"4","shape":"Asscher","pair":"jgj","carats":"1.8","color":"G","clarity":"VS2","service":"iuhi","polish":"hiihi","symetric":"hih","tables":"ihi","measurments":"hi","flourscne":"hi","description":"ih","certificated":"hjgj","ccode":"hjgj","cut":"Signature Ideal","total":"iuhiu","file":"hiuhih","stone":"Single"}]
06-06 12:10:19.825    1237-1237/com.diamond.traders E/log_tag﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Comment: Your server is not returning JSON. You are trying to parse HTML as JSON. This is definitely going to give exception.

Comment: can you tell me what changes i need to do?? i am using similar code for my other classes and it is working perfectly.

Comment: I am sorry, I only know about `Android`. I can show you the path, but can't tell you how to do it. You'll have to search, how to return `JSON` data from server.

Comment: it's fine. Just tell me the steps and i will do the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are return HTML code from your database you should change the result of the statement from the database.

**problem:**
   You forgot to you put `color` parameter in your `NameValuePairs` from this php parameter

```
    $color1 = $_POST['color1'];
$color2 = $_POST['color2'];
```

Comment: can you tell me how to do it? i am using similar server side for other classes and it is working perfectly.

Comment: @SamvidKulkarni so when you try it on a PC's website it will return in json format?

Comment: i don't have website. My client is my android application and output is shown on android application only. Also the format has to be in JSON.

Comment: @SamvidKulkarni in your databse try your statement and check the result in there

Comment: i did check my statement by running the query in phpmyadmin and i am getting perfect result.